# How do I make my smoke move faster?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I’m recreating a scene where someone opens a door, and in the room it’s all foggy and they turn on their lightsaber lighting up the smoke. Im making it into a Lego versions so I imported a model from mecabricks. I forgot that importing from that scales it up a lot, and I already have my scene animated. Im trying to fill up the room with smoke before the door opens, but the smoke moves too slowly because everything is so big. How can I make it move faster? I already have the heat, buoyancy density, and the initial temperature at max. I don’t know how to make it move any faster. Please help!

Comment: In the Domain parameters, there's a Time Scale value, have you tried to tweak it?

Comment: No, I’m not currently near my computer but when I get there I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: @moonboots: not everybody can tweak the time...remember!?

Comment: @Chris hey Chris, still here? I thought you were back in 2055, the 20s must not be so bad after all

Comment: we in 2055 can live in parallel universes in different times at the same time. I could explain this now to you, but it would be as if you explain a 3 year old the "Theory of relativity" - you can do it - but it's waste of time :D

Comment: Is it this “Timesteps” thing where it has (as default) minimum set to 1 and max set to 4?